# Running an external file using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, external, selenium-ide

I am pretty sure this is better accomplished with Webdriver, but is there a way to do this in Selenium IDE?  Specifically, I just want the IDE to have a command line to run an external file (e.g., executable, batch...).

Comment: Reason for downvote, please?  i'm fine with a downvote if this is answered somewhere else and I missed it, but just downvoting because you might not like the question seems unhelpful.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info on what exactly you're wanting the test to do and what would be contained in the external file?

Comment: I am processing some web pages and halfway in the processing I need to execute an external file/exe (AutoIt, etc.) that manages an older application we have, in the workflow.  I am just wondering if Selenium IDE can tell the system to run such an executable.

Comment: In that case I don't think it is possible with the IDE. I know it can pull in data from an external file to use in a script but to my knowledge it can't interact with external files in any way other than that.